# Increased memory Ram of Magento 2.4.2p2 store

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2-p2

I've just increased my servers RAM memory. I have two private servers

Http, Redis for session and Elasticsearch memory: Increased from 64gb to 160gb
Db server with Mysql from 64 to 96gb rams.

Is there any recomendation for magento 2.4.2p2, I mean should I increase for example elasticsearch memory? I have it running on 49.1 gigarams of those 160gb available. If so how much should I increase?

Also regarding Redis, fullpage cache, mysqldb, any recomendation on a new configuration on that.

Thanks

---

Update as @Wilson Hauck (thanks)

Both servers with SSD disks in raid.

Here is he info: https://justpaste.it/39nf5

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Additional OS information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: From your OS Command Prompt, please run  ulimit -a  and press Enter  for list of limits.  What is on the line with Open Files   from the report ?  
Can you also post results of   top -b -n 1 and press Enter  for most active apps ?  Please, Thank You.  What country and time zone are you in?  We are in USA Central Time Zone GMT -5 hours.

Comment: Francisco-Muniz You are running 8.0.30  (became GA on 2022-07-26 - less than 2 months ago).  Please review this URL that points to the CHANGELOG - the volume is more than usual and you likely are experiencing the runtime results.    
URL to the changelog  -  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-30.html  -  
Your workload analysis is in process.  Please provide the information requested in the comment posted 10 hours ago. Thank You.

Comment: Francisco-Muniz  Your com_create_table count of 37,700 in just over 1 day.  What about your application causes this many tables to be created in 1 day?  Are you using replication or preparing to use replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Host named a-mysql to improve performance
by logging in as root and from MySQL Command Prompt, use SET GLOBAL ......

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=30*1024*1024*1024  # for 30G from 512M to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads RPS of 153
read_rnd_buffer_size=16*1024  # for 16K from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 95,418
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to use more of SSD IOPS available
max_connections=2000  # from 2000 to keep 2000 which is still 8 x max_used_connections to be ready for Black Friday
```

remember to update your my.cnf to make these active on next stop/start of instance.

View profile for contact info.  More adjustments are needed.

Comment: @Francisco-Muniz  After 24 hours of uptime with these new values, please leave a comment on your perspective of performance.  Thank You.

Comment: @Francisco-Muniz has your system been running better for the past week?  Thanks, Wilson